# Why can't I manually define a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I have a simple sample which provides:

1. a struct template:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>

   template <typename T>
   struct range_t
   {
       T b, e;
       range_t(T x, T y) : b(x), e(y) {}
       T begin() { return b; }
       T end() { return e; }
   };
   ```
2. a function template:

   ```
   template <typename T>
   range_t<T> range(T b, T e)
   {
       return range_t<T>(b, e);
   }
   ```

I can use it to skip items in foreach loop of a (i.e) `std::vector`:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    for (auto p : range(v.begin()+1, v.end()))
    {
        std::cout << p << " ";
    }
}
```

This works as intended, however I don't really understand the need of the *function template* (2).

I tried to write the foreach loop as this:

```
for (auto p : range_t<std::vector::const_iterator>(v.begin()+1, v.end()))
```

But for this I always got

> error: template argument 1 is invalid

This might be a duplicate question, feel free to mark it as duplicate and please let me know the duplicated question which answers to **all** of these questions:

1. Why is the template argument invalid here?
2. (How) can I skip the function template?
3. How can I create a function template which would work as this:

   *myskipper* would get only `v` as parameter in the foreach loop:

   ```
   template<typename T>
   range_t<T::const_iterator> myskipper(T c) {
     return range_t<T::const_iterator>(c.begin()+1, c.end());
   }

   ...
   for (auto p : myskipper(v)) ...
   ```

Comment: `std::vector::const_iterator` needs to be `std::vector<int>::const_iterator`.  You need to tell it what kind of vector the iterator is from.  For your code under bullet #3, you need `typename T::const_iterator`

Comment: One question per question please. In (3), you also need to pass the container by reference. In (2), you can just write `range_t(foo.begin(), foo.end())`.

Comment: Works (almost) perfectly, can I somehow return with an *empty* range for *foreach*, in case the collection has less items than the advancing factor? How should I modify this: `return range_t<typename T::const_iterator>(v.begin()+10, v.end());` ?

Comment: An empty range is one where first iterator is equal to the second (normally, `begin() == end()`).

Comment: `v.begin()+10` is UB for vectors shorter than 10, so you can't use this syntax. You have to pass the offset separately. Or, there's [`std::views::drop`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/drop_view), if ranges are you thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments and [this](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/cplusplus/CTR55-CPP.+Do+not+use+an+additive+operator+on+an+iterator+if+the+result+would+overflow) article about iterator overflow, here a complete [working example](https://replit.com/@Orace/SO72275836):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct range_t
{
    T b, e;
    range_t(T x, T y) : b(x), e(y) {}
    T begin() { return b; }
    T end() { return e; }
};

template <typename T>
range_t<T> range(T b, T e)
{
    return range_t<T>(b, e);
}

template<typename T>
range_t<typename T::iterator> skip(T &c, typename T::size_type skipCount)
{
  return range_t<typename T::iterator>(c.begin() + std::min(c.size(), skipCount), c.end());
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    for (auto p : range(v.begin()+1, v.end()))
    {
        std::cout << p << " ";
    }
    
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
    for (auto p : range_t(v.begin()+1, v.end()))
    {
        std::cout << p << " ";
    }
    
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
    for (auto p : skip(v, 3))
    {
        std::cout << p << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```